# accentuate the boldness of a font swift

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

Is it possible to accentuate the boldness of a font? I used this font :

```
lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 22)
```

But it's not bold enough. I would like to have this :

**Desired font**

[image: Screen shot]

But I have this :

**Current font**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use an NSAttributedString to which you have applied an `.expansion` attribute.

For example, here's some text in Arial-BoldMT size 22:

[image]

And here's the same text in the same font, but with an expansion factor of 0.2:

[image]